# Why map transformation is narrow?

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, rdd

I'm aware of difference between narrow and wide transformations for RDD. My question is what are the parameters which certifies map, flatmap as narrow? Why aren't these transformations wide? Any suggestions on RDD learning material  is appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Here is one explanation](http://backtobazics.com/big-data/spark/apache-spark-rdd-operations-transformation-and-action/)

> – Narrow dependency:  RDD operations like map, union, filter can operate on a single partition and map the data of that partition to resulting single partition. These kind of operations which maps data from one to one partition are referred as Narrow operations. Narrow operations doesn’t required to distribute the data across the partitions.
>
> – Wide dependency: RDD operations like groupByKey, distinct, join may require to map the data across the partitions in new RDD. These kind of operations which maps data from one to many partitions are referred as Wide operations

Another way to think of it is this. Any row of the child RDD will depend on only 1 row of the parent RDD. Since each child row can point to the 1 parent row it depends on, there is a narrow dependency.